# importing a module and altering the module behavior at import

Tags: python

I want to import a module, but the import may behave differently depending on some external condition I want to impose. What are the strategies available to achieve this result ?

example. I want a module foo.py. If I `import foo` I get a print of "hello" or "goodbye" depending on some external condition which is independent on the module, and is instead dependent on external factors. A trivial one may be a global variable, but I don't think the python scoping rules allow me to get global variables from outside the module foo.

Example:

fop.py

```
import __main__
try:
    __main__.bar
    present = True
except:
    present = False

if present:
    print "present"
else:
    print "not present"
```

Now, when I import the module, I can obtain different results

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Feb 27 2011, 20:04:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import foo
not present
>>> 

Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Feb 27 2011, 20:04:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> bar = 5
>>> import foo
present
```

I know it's weird, but I have a very, very, very good reason to do it.

Comment: Sounds like code no one will ever understand...

Comment: Sebastian : that's _exactly_ what I want to achieve

Comment: Can you give an example of the use case? Such as an example of the external condition, and what constitutes "behave differently"?

Comment: Ah ok, you should check out twisted.internet.reactor in that case, it seems like a good way to me.

Comment: You can do call kinds of things through the import hooks: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/

Answer (score 0):

You actually can access global variables of the main script from inside a module.

In the main script:

```
a = 42
import foo
```

In `foo.py`:

```
import __main__
print __main__.a
```

Note that I only stated that this is possible :)

Comment: that's nice. Other methods to achieve the same ?

Answer (score 0):

A standard means of passing around data about the environment is to (naturally) use an environment variable:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['PY_BAR'] = '1'
>>> import foo
"present"
```

Another possible pattern is to implement a custom **import** routine / hook, so that when `foo` is imported, the initialization routine mentioned below can be silently executed after the module is loaded but before control is returned.

---

Extending Sven's pattern, you could make the initialization of `foo` module explicit so that the external environment can influence it.  This creates a well-defined, documented interface for injecting state into the `foo` module before it is used:

Define the **foo.py** module:

```
# define all your classes and functions, then leave global stubs which will 
# be filled in by the module initialization function init(), which _must_ be
# called before the module is used.

_DATA = {}

def use_data():
    # use '_DATA' to do something useful
    ...

def init(state):
    # use 'state' to populate '_DATA'
    ...
```

Define the **main** script:

```
# main configures the state, passing it explicitly to foo
state = {'variable': 42}
import foo
foo.init(state)
foo.use_data()
```

Comment: nope, that does not work. I want to control the module __at__ the import, not after it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [virtual module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368057/making-a-virtual-package-available-via-sys-modules) Like this you can define your module somewhere, put everything you want inside and every time you import it you'll get this virtual module and not the original one. When the external condition changes, you just redo the whole thing and put something else into the module.

If you have different files for the different behaviours, you can also change the search path of a package in its `__init__.py` if your condition changes, you just have to remove it from sys.modules so it is actually reloaded on the next import.