# Python: Create virtual import path

Tags: python, import

Is there any way to create a virtual import path in Python?

My directory structure is like this:

- /

  - native

    - scripts

      - some.py
      - another.py
    - [Other unrelated dirs]

The root is the directory from where the program is executed. Atm I add `native/scripts/` to the search path so I can do `import some, another` instead of `from native.scripts import some, another`, but I'd like to be able to do it like this:

```
from native import some
import native.another
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

---

> **Related questions:**
>   [Making a virtual package available via sys.modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368057)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not move `some.py` and `another.py` out into the `native` directory so that everything Just Works and so that people returning to the source code later won't be confused about why things are and aren't importable? :)

**Update:**

Thanks for your comments; they have usefully clarified the problem! In your case, I generally put functions and classes that I might want to import inside, say, `native.some` where I can easily get to them. But then I get the script code, and *only* the script code — only the thin shim that interprets arguments and starts everything running by passing those to a `main()` or `go()` function as parameters — and put *that* inside of a `scripts` directory. That keeps external-interface code cleanly separate from code that you might want to import, and means you don't have to try to fool Python into having modules several places at once.

Comment: Why not just put all the files in the root and be done with it. ;)

Comment: I keep files out of the root to avoid name conflicts with the Standard Library and 3rd-party modules I might need from PyPI — I only wind up taking one name out at the top level, rather than several. That's why. :)

Comment: What I'm writing is an application that embeds Python, not on written in Python. In my specific context, things would be much nicer if I could refer to the native scripts through the `native` package, without polluting the directory itself.

Answer (score 2):

In `/native/__init__.py`, include:

```
from scripts import some, another
```

Comment: Note that this will only work if he also has an `__init__.py` inside of `scripts` itself. (Maybe that's obvious to him?) Also, this means that the scripts are not imported on demand, but will always be imported the moment `native` itself is imported; but in most cases that does not matter.

Comment: That's one solution, but then I can't do `import native.some` &mdash; I'd also like to be able to do that.

Comment: @Paul Why don't you just move `some.py` and `other.py` to `native/` then? It looks like that's what you actually want.

Comment: @phihag That'd just make `native` very messy. Native contains some other subdirs like `animations`, `screens`, `sounds`. I'd like it if the scripts also had their own subdir.